# The use of wasn't and weren't in second conditional structure?

Tags: conditionals

I have a question about the 2nd conditional structure. I've search it through the site, but still can't come up with a proper answer.

- If the weather ___ so bad, we could go to the zoo.

What should we fill in the gap, "wasn't" or "weren't"? Can the two be possible?
Please explain and include a reference if it is available.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you used a dictionary to see the difference between 'weren't' and 'wasn't'? Questions that can be answered that way are off-topic here.

Comment: I've read about it via Cambridge dictionary online. However, I really need an answer for this question as it has been used in a recent exam of my child. I'm just a non-native English speaker, so I'm not sure about this grammar point. Please help!

Comment: @Astralbee, no dictionary has definitions for negative contractions as separate from their non-negative counterparts because they're not words. Even in the case of a legitimate single-word auxiliary contraction like "cannot", a dictionary wouldn't say anything about grammatical subtleties. A better reference would be Swan's Practical English Usage or similar, but that's not a dictionary, so this question is on-topic.

Comment: @gotube No dictionary, except all of the major ones. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wasn-t

Comment: @gotube Even if a dictionary simply defines the contraction, one can then use the dictionary to look up the words in the contraction.

Comment: @Astralbee I didn't find any major dictionary that had either 1) a separate definition for "wasn't/weren't" beyond "was not/were not", or 2) grammatical details on either contraction, like meaning or usage in unreal conditionals. If you could cite an example of something pertinent to the OP's question from a dictionary, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As the sentence seems to be talking about the present, "wasn't" is the grammatically correct choice. Note, however, that many people in casual speech might well use "weren't" here, and a fluent speaker would understand this as having the same meaning.

Note also that terms like "second conditional" represent an oversimplification used as a teaching device for ESL learners. This classification is not taught to or used by native speakers, and it excludes many valid conditional forms that are easy to get wrong.

Comment: Actually, the "super correct" choice is **if the weather weren't so bad**, but **wasn't** is acceptable nowadays. The throwback "subjunctive" causes a lot of confusion.